# Connect to kvm instance via VNC and view X session

Tags: xorg, vnc, kvm-virtualization

I've launched an Ubuntu 11.10 instance (oneiric-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img downloaded from [here](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/oneiric/current/)) inside of KVM, with VNC enabled. I can connect to the instance using VNC, and I see a login prompt.

I'd like to be able to use this VNC connection to show an X session instead of a text prompt. What do I need to install/configure so that this VNC session exposed through KVM shows an X11 session?

(Note that I can successfully switch between tty[1-6] by doing Ctl-Alt-F#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to install lightdm and unity-2d:

```
apt-get install lightdm unity-2d
service lightdm start
```

The KVM vnc will then default to the login page, which is X-based.